# How could a package be installed without internet connection

Tags: apt, package-management

I installed a package named "vbaexpress" on my ubuntu and to uninstall it I purged it using

```
sudo apt-get purge vbaexpress
```

and to uninstall it's dependencies I autoremoved it by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove vbaexpress
```

At this point I assume that the package was completely uninstalled from my computer but when I typed

```
sudo apt-get install vbaexpress
```

it got installed even when my computer was not connected to Internet. Why did it happen? Did it get wrong with my assumption of getting the package completely un-installed? If yes, how can I remove it completely?

Comment: The installer package was probably cached. Cached packages should be located in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. If you run `sudo apt-get clean` they'll be deleted.

Comment: Also, afaik you only need to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` not `sudo apt-get autoremove <packagename>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is completely uninstalled, but your system is configured by default so that the downloaded DEB files will not be deleted after an installation.

Therefore start

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

to delete packages that can no longer be downloaded, or

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to delete all downloaded packages

---

from `man apt-get`

```
clean
    clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It
    removes everything but the lock file from /var/cache/apt/archives/ and
    /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.

autoclean
    Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved
    package files. The difference is that it only removes package files
    that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This allows
    a cache to be maintained over a long period without it growing out of
    control. The configuration option APT::Clean-Installed will prevent
    installed packages from being erased if it is set to off.
```

Answer (score 0):

After the purge operation the package is effectively uninstalled. The isn't any file from the package usable by your system. The reason you could install it again, is because apt will cache any package downloaded from the repositories, to prevent redownloads of the same package, wasting mirrors bandwidth. The package cache resides in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

If you are a Windows user, an equivalent behavior is: downloading an installer, then unplugging the network cable and then installing the software.